# Nginx rewrite rule not working when service redirects

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx rule

```
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location ^~ /geosamples/ {
       rewrite  ^/geosamples/(.*)$  /geoserver/$1  break;
       proxy_pass http://192.168.92.100:8088;
       proxy_connect_timeout 180s;
       proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }
```

If I access the application at
    mydomain.com/geosamples/index.html
it works fine.

If I access it at

```
mydomain.com/geosamples/
```

it gets redirected to

```
mydomain.com/geoserver/index.html
```

and obviously doesn't work anymore!

I am guessing the geoserver app is redirecting the client to this buggy URL...

How can I prevent this? I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `proxy_redirect` directive to reverse your `rewrite` when the upstream server returns a 3xx response.

Try:

```
proxy_redirect http://example.com/geoserver/ http://example.com/geosamples/;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for the details.

Comment: Thanks, I did the following but no luck proxy_redirect http://example.com/geoserver/ http://example.com/geosamples/;

Comment: The `proxy_redirect` needs to match the `Location` header in the 3xx response. Use a browser plug-in to analyse the exact response coming from your server, so that you can make sure that the `proxy_redirect` contains the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You just don't need to overcomplicate things.

```
location ^~ /geosamples/ {
   proxy_pass http://192.168.92.100:8088/geoserver/;
   proxy_connect_timeout 180s;
   proxy_read_timeout 240s;
}
```